# Mass/Bulk Update Campaign Member Status Over 200

Tags: apex, javascript, dml, campaign-member, apex-webservice

I am looking to update all of the related Campaign Members' Statuses from a Campaign based on the execution of a JavaScript button and an APEX Class. The button below works to update the status from 'Added' to 'Sent'; however, I hit the DML governor limits for a query where campaign members with an 'added' status is >200.

**Javascript button**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")} 
var id= '{!Campaign.Id}'; 
alert('Updating Campaign Members...'); 
sforce.apex.execute('updatesentcampmembers','updateRecord',{recId :id}); 
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

**Apex Class**

```
global class updatesentcampmembers {
    webservice static void updateRecord(Id recId){
        List campmember = [SELECT id, status FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId =:recId and status='Added'];
        for (CampaignMember campm : campmember){
        campm.status='Sent';
        }
        update campmember;
    }
}
```

I believe the problem lies with the APEX class. I was trying to convert it using [Best Practice #6: Querying Large Data Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) seems to throw me an error that 'campm' doesn't exist.

**Failed bulkify class**

```
global class updatesentcampmembers {
    webservice static void updateRecord(Id recId){
        for (List campm : [SELECT id, status FROM CampaignMember WHERE CampaignId =:recId and status='Added']){
        campaignmember.status='distributed';
        }
        update campm;
    }
}
```

Note: The final script would have additional IF statements only when certain criteria is met within the campaign so a marketer does not accidentally execute it.

As you may have guessed, I'm pretty new to the development scene. Thanks for any help!